# Building a WFS whose features hold lists of records

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoserver, wfs, relates

I've got two tables in a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database:

1. `UTM` (geom geometry(Polygon,25830),utmcode character varying(6))
2. `Species` (species_name character varying(50), utmcode character varying(6), category int)

The first one holds a UTM 10x10 km grid and the second, bird species and in which UTM cell they were recorded, categorized (the higher the number for "category", the better).

I've built a *Relationship* in QGIS between both tables that returns the list of species recorded in a particular cell, using the *Spatial Objects Identification tool*. So far, so good.

[image]

What I need now is to replicate the procedure to create a WFS service using Geoserver, but I can't figure out how to create such a *relationship* in PostgreSQL/PostGIS. How should it be done?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create the relationship via SQL. You could either write the query directly in the layer definition on Geoserver or create a view in the database and select this view.

SQL ([Postgre Joins](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html)):

```sql
SELECT 
   s.species_name, 
   u.utmcode,
   u.geom 
FROM 
   utm u 
JOIN 
   species s 
ON 
   u.utmcode = s.utmcode;
```

Geoserver Steps:

1. [Create a Workspace](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/webadmin/workspaces.html)
2. [Create a Datastore which connects Geoserver to your DB](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/app-schema/data-stores.html)
3. [Create a Layer based on your view (Publish directly) or write the SQL statement in the layer definition.](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html)

[You would also need to configure WFS either globally or on workspace level.](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/webadmin.html#workspace)

[You can test your setting via the layer preview.](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/webadmin/layerpreview.html)
Select WFS on the Output Format Dropdown.

Afterwards add the WFS to QGIS.

Comment: But, wouldn't such a query create as many geometries per cell as species recorded in it? If so, each WFS request would yield only one species, instead of the list that I'm looking for.

Comment: WFS can only be used for geographical data. So you would have one cell per species. For your list you would need to have the species in a separate table and join them on the client (like you are doing). You would need some REST middleware to host your none-geodata (if you would like to do it with services -- WFS + REST). Another approach would be to directly connect to your database without using Geoserver / WFS at all and use your current approach.  https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html?highlight=db%20browser#the-db-manager

Comment: If you still want to go with WFS you could aggregate your data in SQL and create your list in one field (using some seperation character) using group by.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution (not ideal, though) using a dynamic pivot (https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2018/06/19/crosstab-pivot.html).

```
CREATE TABLE atlas AS
   WITH tabla AS (SELECT utmcode,
                 json_object_agg(species_name,total ORDER BY species_name) AS list
                 FROM (
                       SELECT utmcode, species_name, max(category) AS total
                       FROM atlas
                       GROUP BY utmcode,species_name
                      ) s
                 GROUP BY utmcode
                 ORDER BY utmcode)
   SELECT utm.utmcode, utm.geom, tabla.list
   FROM utm 
     INNER JOIN 
     tabla on tabla.utmcode = utm.utmcode
;
```

This creates a table that yields all species in each cell and their category figures as a json object in one column, and it can be served with the WFS service.